# so i was making a gfx and then i pressed a random button and this screen popped up. any help would be great

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine

[image]This is the screen that i am seeing currently. I have tried clicking esc on my keyboard, and nothing works. I am really stumped and I don't know if there is any possible way to get out of this screen.

Comment: I also really don't want to restart so if you know any way of getting out of this, please add it here.

Comment: If you move your mouse to the top-right corner area, is there a spot where 2 arrows appear? Also, try pressing `Ctrl + Alt + Space` (toggles fullscreen).

Comment: Omg yes. I didn't realize that..thank you so much.